# DatabaseMetaData getProcedureColumns stored procedure column names order?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc, callable-statement, database-metadata

I use databasemetadata to get columns (read parameters) of a stored procedure on SQL server:

```
Connection connection = getConnection(); //getting the connection -   
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData();

HashMap<String, Integer> paramInfo = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
if (dbMetaData != null){
    ResultSet rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns (null, null, sp_name.toUpperCase(), "%");
    while (rs.next())
        paramInfo.put(rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(6));
    rs.close();
}
```

Does `getProcedureColumns()` return the procedure columns in an ordered way? Meaning if in the database the stored procedure parameters are- `abc(@a int,@b int,@c int)`, would I always get `@a, @b and @c` in an ordered way?

If yes, is there any documentation to suggest the same?

Answer (score 2):

All JDBC drivers are required to follow the JDBC specification and API documentation, and the API documentation of [`DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) specifies:

> Retrieves a description of the given catalog's stored procedure
>   parameter and result columns.
>
> Only descriptions matching the schema, procedure and parameter name
>   criteria are returned. They are ordered by `PROCEDURE_CAT`,
>   `PROCEDURE_SCHEM`, `PROCEDURE_NAME` and `SPECIFIC_NAME`. Within this,
>   the return value, if any, is first. Next are the parameter
>   descriptions in call order. The column descriptions follow in column
>   number order.

If a driver does not follow this specification, then that is a bug in the driver. So in general you should be able to rely on above description.

Otherwise, check the values in columns `COLUMN_TYPE` (index 5) which specifies the type (in parameter, result set column, etc) and `ORDINAL_POSITION` (index 18) which describes the position (check the details in the javadoc).

Comment: Furthermore, the `SQLServerDatabaseMetaData#getProcedureColumns` source code reveals that it calls the SQL Server system stored procedure `sp_sproc_columns`, whose [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sproc-columns-transact-sql) says that "The results returned are ordered by PROCEDURE_QUALIFIER, PROCEDURE_OWNER, PROCEDURE_NAME, and the order that the parameters appear in the procedure definition."